# Modal event is not working angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, typescript, angular

I am trying to clear form values when modal is hidden using its event but it not working I am referencing all the required files but it not trigger. Below I attach the code of my client side. I am using it in my angular 2 application as an component.

### html

```html
<script src="../../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
    });
</script>



<button type="button" class="btn-u pull-right margin-bottom-10" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Invite User</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Invite User</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" id='myForm' role="form" [ngFormModel]="InviteUserForm">
                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='inviteUser.username' class="form-control" ngControl="username" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                        <input type="email" required [(ngModel)]='inviteUser.email' class="form-control" ngControl="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-glass"></i></span>
                        <select [(ngModel)]='inviteUser.partnerId' class="form-control" ngControl="partner" required>
                            <option>Select one</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let partner of _partners" value={{partner.Id}}>
                                {{partner.Name}}
                            </option>
                        </select>

                    </div>

                </form>
                <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-u-default margin-right-5" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" [disabled]="!InviteUserForm.valid" class="btn-u pull-right" (click)="Invite(inviteUser)" data-dismiss="modal">Invite</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why do you use jquery in angular2 project

Comment: how to do this in angular 2

Comment: i will give an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular2 bootstrap modal as https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal. You can import this plugin into your project.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
constructor() {
  this.activate();
}

activate() {

  ////This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.
  ///called to reset the events and the headers.
  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    ////debugger;
    // do your work over here
    console.log("modal is closed hidden");
  })


  ////This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the   user (will wait for css transitions to complete).
  ///called to reset the events and the headers.
  $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    ////debugger;
    // do your work over here;

    console.log("modal is closed hide");
  })
}
```